# phonegap / iphone / zxing

Tags: iphone, cordova, zxing

I need to add Zxing (a qrcode reader app) to my iphone app, made in html, css & js, phonagap compiled.

I have the zxing app on a side & my app (phonegap based) on the other side.

If someone knows what can I do to add the zxing project (a qrcode reader function) to my phonegap based app... It will great & really appreciated !

Any advice is welcome !

Thanks,

Nico

Comment: You do know that the new Apple terms do not allow apps built with 3rd parties like Phonegap  right ?

Comment: Completely wrong, Phonegap is expressly permitted by Apple even under the IOS 4 Terms and Conditions.  See http://www.phonegap.com/2010/04/14/phonegap-and-the-apple-developer-license-agreement/

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like : http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html under phoneGap